# Why is Saxon throwing an error with the CentOS-distributed saxon.jar, but not with the saxon code from sourceforge?

Tags: centos, java, xslt

I have an existing CentOS 7 server (setup by someone else, of course) running Saxon.  If I run:

```
/usr/bin/java net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:input.xml -xsl:input.xsl -o:output.xml
```

...it works perfectly.

On a new server, I've installed Saxon via "yum install saxon".  If I attempt the same command, it fails with the error:

```
Error at HTML on line 19 column 38 of 2.xsl:
  XTSE0150: Simplified stylesheet: xsl:version attribute is missing
Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
```

If I download the latest Saxon from sourceforge.net/projects/saxon, redirect my CLASSPATH from the yum-installed saxon.jar (dated 2014!) to the jar files from sourceforge, the transform works perfectly.

So, I have a FIX for the problem (i.e. use the latest from sourceforge, not CentOS's out-dated version) but I'm still curious as to what's going on.

Is this simply some old bug that's fixed in a newer release?  Or maybe I'm missing supporting files that are in the sourceforge-derived jars, but not in the yum-derived files?  Or something else???

For what it's worth, here's the head of my XSLT file.  The error is specifically pointing at the end of the xsl:stylesheet tag, although there is clearly a "version=" setting in that config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:oai-pmh="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/"
     xmlns:oai_qdc="http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/qdc-1.0/"
     xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
     xmlns:dcmitype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/"
     xmlns:edm="http://www.europeana.eu/schemas/edm/"
     xmlns:oclcdc="http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/oclcdc-1.0/"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/qdc-1.0/
                  http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/qdc/1.0/qdc-1.0.xsd
                  http://purl.org/net/oclcterms
                  http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/oclcterms/1.4/oclcterms-1.4.xsd"
     exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
     version="2.0"
     xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3">
```

Given that the code works perfectly fine with the alternate Saxon install, I don't believe that there's a problem with the code.  It's something else, but I don't know what...

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which version of Saxon is in a particular JAR file by doing

```
java -cp saxon.jar net.sf.saxon.Version
```

and this would be a lot more useful than just telling us where you installed it from.

The error message suggests to me that the "stylesheet" being used is actually not a stylesheet at all, but an ordinary XML document. (Saxon sees that the root element isn't `xsl:stylesheet`, so it decides it must be a simplified stylesheet; then it looks for the `xsl:version` attribute, finds that there isn't one, and complains).

I don't know exactly what's wrong here, but the application is using an invocation of Saxon that works with one release and doesn't work with the other. There haven't been many incompatible changes to the command line interface over the 20 years of Saxon's life, but there have been a few, and I suspect one of these Saxon versions is very old indeed.

**AFTERTHOUGHT**

There's another clue which I missed on first reading: the error message refers to a file called `2.xsl`. From the supplied information, we can't see what `2.xsl` is. It must be the file that appears to be a stylesheet but isn't... But why does it have a different name? Certainly the fact that your file has the end of the start tag at line 19, and so does this mystery file, appears significant. Perhaps there's some script that's being executed before Saxon actually gets invoked, and that creates `2.xsl`?

Comment: The "2.xsl" was just an artifact of me changing filenames during my write-up to try to make it more obvious by renaming filenames in the example from "2.xsl" to "input.xsl".  I neglected to change the filename in the error output, too.  Sorry...I only caught that error after I reloaded the page to check for responses.

FWIW...the Saxon installed by yum is displaying the following version information:

SAXON 9.3.0.4 from Saxonica (build 122216)

Comment: 9.3.0.4 is certainly rather old (2010-12-22) and hasn't even been updated with bug fixing maintenance releases (the last on the 9.3 branch was 9.3.0.11). Having said that, if this is a Saxon bug then it's a rather unlikely one. But I'm afraid there's no way we're going to investigate a problem in an ancient release that doesn't occur in a more recent one.